# What the rank of a matrix with the elements of one column to be infinity?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Suppose the $m\times m$ real matrix $A$ is positive definite, it is without doubt that $\mathrm{rank} (A) = m$. Now, if all the elements in the first column and first row are assigned to be infinity, what is the rank of $A$?

Numerically, since other elements can be viewed as zero, thus we have $\mathrm{rank}(A) = 2$. However, I wonder whether it is theoretically established.

Thanks for 5xum, the restriction of "real matrix" is removed.

Comment: What is the *meaning* of rank in that context?

Comment: The issue is that infinity is not a real number. So, more context is needed here. Are you working with sequences of matrices with entries growing without bound?

Comment: Yes, I have encountered the problem to deal with sequences of matrices with entries growing without bound. More specifically, it involves the inversion operation. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @yuhu then in this case post that problem here and people will address it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following two statements are in direct contradiction:

> Suppose the $m\times m$ **real** matrix $A$

> if all the elements in the first column and first row are assigned to be **infinity**

Infinity is not a real number, this, if the all elements are asigned to be "infinity", then the matrix is no longer a real matrix.

---

In general:

- The *rank* of a matrix is defined as the number of linearly independent columns of $A$ (or, equivalently, as the dimension of the image of $A$).
- Linear dependency (and dimensionality) are defined for vector spaces.
- Vector spaces are defined over fields.

The above means that, in order to speak about the rank of a matrix, the elements of that matrix must, by definition, be elements of the **field** over which the vector space you are examining is defined. So before asking about the rank of a matrix that includes $\infty$ as its element, you need to define which field you are looking at this in. And no, that field cannot be $\mathbb R$, because $\infty\notin\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. It seems that such a problem do not exist. Is there any possibility that this problem be well defined (e.g., the choice of field) and how about the treatment in such situation?  Actually, I have encountered an engineering problem to deal with sequences of matrices with entries growing without bound. If it is still very vague, do you have any suggestions to deal with such real matrices with specific rows and columns to be very large (e.g., in the inversion operations)?

Comment: @yuhu Without knowing the details of a problem, I can't really comment on it. But the point still stands that $\infty\notin \mathbb R$.